# How to prevent modifying a design time component in derived form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have defined a base VCL form class with a (non-visual) designtime component on it that contains a collection of styles.

I want to prevent developers (and myself) to change those styles in the forms that are derived from my base form. To speak in C# terms, I would like the component to be sealed in the base VCL form.

How can I achieve that?

On a side note: I never did understand the declaration of designtime components on a form in Delphi.. kinda public but not placed in the public section of the class declaration. Can anybody explain the reason for this?

Comment: An application of self-discipline usually does the job.

Comment: If self-discipline was all it takes ... than there would be no need for private, protected and public properties, would there? .........

Comment: Visibility levels do more though. They also provide documentation of what the interface is. As for your question I can't really picture your current code.

Comment: How do you achieve the opposite?

Comment: +David Hefferman I'm asking about how to make a non-visual designtime component on a VCL form "sealed" if you like, to speak in C# terms.
+Agustin Ortu: I don't understand what you mean by "achieve the opposite"

Comment: How does the C# sealed analogues in your situation? A sealed class cannot be used as a base class.

Comment: @kobik, only the component with the styles collection should be sealed, or am I missing something?

Comment: @LURD, would that prevent the descendant Forms from changing this component published **properties** in the ide?

Comment: Maybe "protect" the published setters by testing the `Self` class and making sure only the base class can use the setter property.

Comment: "declaration of designtime components on a form in Delphi.. kinda public" - they are PUBLISHED not PUBLIC, and that means they generate RTTI for the "reflection" used by IDE in design-time and also for streaming the form into and from DFM files/resources

Comment: @kobik another option, but hardly possible with the topicstarter experience level, is making those styles PROTECTED and only exposing them to IDE/VCL via `DefineProperties method`. Then the custom properties writer could ignore all the changes made in derivative classes and only allow base form's data to be streamed.

Comment: @Arioch Ok, you are right, they are published, I stand corrected ... but still makes me wonder why they are not in a published section then (or is the default section published )?

Comment: @Bascy yes, classes usually start with an implicit published section, records and interfaces with an implicit public section. Basically you can prepend visibility clause to EVERY member if that is what you got used to in .Net - that would make new section for every member :-)

Comment: Quoting documentation that you somehow missed to read: "If a member's declaration appears without its own visibility specifier, the member has the same visibility as the one that precedes it. Members at the beginning of a class declaration that do not have a specified visibility are by default published, provided the class is compiled in the {$M+} state or is derived from a class compiled in the {$M+} state; otherwise, such members are public."  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Classes_and_Objects#Visibility_of_Class_Members

Comment: @arioch Glad that that part of my question has been clarified. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, short answer you can't. In case you really need it I would suggest to create the component in run-time and make it private. If you are using GExpert ([click here](http://www.gexperts.org/)) you may use "Components to Code" command to get the required code. If you need more details, please share your DFM file and I will post the corresponding code here.

As for your side note, the components are declared as **published**. See [Visibility of Class Members](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Classes_and_Objects) quote

> If a member's declaration appears without its own visibility
>   specifier, the member has the same visibility as the one that precedes
>   it. Members at the beginning of a class declaration that do not have a
>   specified visibility are by default published, provided the class is
>   compiled in the {$M+} state or is derived from a class compiled in the
>   {$M+} state; otherwise, such members are public

**NB** `TForm` is a descendant of `TPersistent` which is compiled with `{$M+}` directive

**PS** the published declaration is required for `TComponent.SetName` (actually `TComponent.SetReference`) which should assign the component reference to the corresponding field when you modifying the component `Name` property.